# SQL server object explorer doesnt show my databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have at least 7 databases in local, my projects are just working fine. Now i just want to be able to delete some of them, but I can not see any database in the SQL server object explorer, im using visual studio 2013 and i have installed all the latest updates.

[image]

Is there any special incantation i can call to make it do its job ?

thanks.

Update:

[image]

Update2:

[image]

Comment: Did you check your user permission to database acces?

Comment: @Phx how can i do that ?

Comment: Expand Security folder and check the users that you have. Check there the user permission.

Comment: i just want to understand something. im using windows 8, so im connected to my computer using my credential. visual studio has a proper license key and running with admin rights. why in the name of god i must grant access to myself in my own local development !

Comment: Are you a sysadmin on the instance?  Do you need to refresh the object explorer?  Have you tried dropping the databases with T-SQL `DROP DATABASE dbname`?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg no i dont think im a sysadmin since i can see any db, and i can not delete databases using a drop statement i need to see their names first.
How can i use any credentials to get access ?

Comment: In the Security, right click your login and click Properties.  Go to the Server Roles tab and check sysadmin.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg as u can see there is no Server Roles tab in the propreties :(

Comment: @dafriskymonkey are you having any disk access or profile issues? I'm wondering if the MDF/LDF files are still there for your DBs? For localdb they're stored in something like C:\Users\dafrisky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\<Project Name>, maybe check that the files are actually there?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to guide you through in SSMS.  I don't know how to make a user sysadmin in VS - it may not be possible.  Do you have SSMS?

Comment: @KevinDahl indeed the 'C:\Users\DaFrisky\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\v12.0' is empty so whats the issue ?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg nop man !! im downloading SSMS right now.

Comment: @dafriskymonkey Try doing a search on your C drive for the db file, it should be called <database name>.mdf. Maybe the .mdf and .ldf files were already deleted via another means?

Comment: @KevinDahl no they are all in the App_Data folder of my projects

Comment: @dafriskymonkey Then they likely won't show up unless that project is loaded.

Comment: the project is loaded :(

Comment: @dafriskymonkey Can you try double clicking the file in App_Data and see if that loads the db into localdb then?

Comment: @KevinDahl yeah it does open the db in the Server explorer, not yet in the SSOE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57420/discussion-between-kevin-dahl-and-dafriskymonkey).

Answer (score 0):

I found i solution thanks to @KevinDahl. (LocalDb)**V11.0** was not loaded in the SSOE. (I dont know why it doesnt load it by default !!).

I  did the following steps:

- double click on the .mdf file in the solution explorer
- right click the db in the server explorer the "Browse to Sql Server Object Explorer".

I hope it will help someone someday.

Thanks all.